# Drag and Resize Position:Absolute all of a sudden stopped working. What can I do?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

For some reason the drag and resize image code in HTML is not working in Dreamweaver any more and I am lost.

```
<div style="position: absolute"><img src="images/Headshot.JPG" width="4608" height="3456" alt=""/></div>
```

I have another site that I just opened up and it was working last month. I had to switch SSDs because of a crash from another problem that I had, but it is on a Samsung 970 Pro now. It just will not work and I have absolutely no idea how else there is to conveniently position an image and resize it. Does anyone know what the problem might be? I cannot even resize anything with the three black squares that normally show up on an image when it is inserted by default.

Comment: headshot.jpg?nice.

Answer (score 0):

Position: absolute; mostly works with the position: relative; parent.ifyou are not using relative parent than it should work fine...and clear your question what do you want to ask?

Comment: I am very unlearned in HTML and web programming and have been relying on this code to move images since 2016. I just pulled up an HTML file for the first time in 2 months that the code was working in and I remember that yellow box showing around the image and now there is nothing. And I cannot even create them in a new environment. I thought maybe it was because I might not have had all of my C++ redistributable packages. Since it was a new install of windows that I was now running on. But, that did not work either. I am lost.

Comment: can you show me a piece of code or live link of your web/page? maybe there will be a z-index issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please first check your code. Write some units (like: px ,em, %) with height and width. You only write the number not unit.
Follow my code.

```
<div style="position= absolute"><img src="images/Headshot.JPG" width="4608px" height="3456px" alt=""/></div>
```

use this code. Otherwise use external css instead of inline or internal.

Comment: Is there any other way to conveniently drag and resize an image other than in coding in CSS? The three black squares that resize an image do not even show up by default when anything is inserted and that is not what was happening a couple of months ago. The numbers that represent the units show up in the code by default.